# Turning Putty Login Credentials Into C# MySqlConnection Connection String

Tags: c#, mysql, putty

I'm having a bit of trouble connecting to my SQL database through my C# code. I can connect to it fine using Putty and the server I am connecting to is based in Germany, I am here in the UK.

When I use Putty I use these credentials:

```
 Host Name:
 sample-intra.net

 Port:
 2223
```

And then to login using the window that opens I type

```
 login as: my_username
 password: my_password
```

then once access has been granted I type:

```
 mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

and then when asked for the password I enter

```
 my_password
```

once again.

That works fine and I can access my database (called `SampleDB`) fine, and access all the tables, but I am having trouble turning this in to a C# connection string I can use with the `SqlConnection` object. If someone can provide me with the connection string based on the above credentials I would appreciate it greatly.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're first connecting with PuTTY to SSH into your server, and then running `mysql` commands while connected, it's as if you're physically sitting at the console of the server. In other words, you connected to your mysql instance using the address "localhost" because you are indeed already on that machine.

There's two things you could do here to work around your problem:

1. [Make an SSH tunnel in PuTTY](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=ssh%20tunnel), and connect to your MySQL
   instance through it.
2. [Enable remote access in your MySQL server
   for connections from your desktop machine's IP address](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html).

Option one is more secure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The SSH tunnel approach is what was suggested to me but I wasn't quite sure how to use this in my C# code?

Comment: @Greenhouse - it's separate from your c# code.  It's something you set up on the server.

Comment: @Greenhouse - once your SSH tunnel is set up in the c# code you will connect to localhost instead of your actual address.  The port will be whatever port you configured in your ssh tunnel (probably the same as the remote port, or one off if you have a local service already running - just a convention though)

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, not had much experience in this area! Basically I now have Putty open, I went to SSH > Tunnels > For Source Port I put 0, and for Destination I put 'localhost:2223' (2223 is the port I was told to connect on by the guy who set up the server for me). I Open this and log in with my username and password fine. I left it open and used the connection string "Server=localhost;Database=my_db_name;User ID=root;Password=my_password;" (with my actual password and db name in obviously) but still no joy? Even if I specify a port number by "server=localhost,0" it doesn't work...

Comment: What I did instead was forget Putty, and used the brilliant SharpSSH project by Tamir Gal. I tweaked it a bit to my needs but it works much better than the MSDN SqlConnection library. Thanks for your help all.